# The ImportError when importing 64bit dlls within 32bit python interpreter

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit

The error code for importing a 32bit code in a 64bit `python` interpreter is

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Is this the same error that is raised when importing 64bit code in a 32bit `python` interpreter?

If not, what is that error?

Comment: A clarification comment: My particular machine is Windows `64bit`. If the machine is able to run both `32bit` and `64bit` python interpreters it implies it must be a `64bit` machine also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I misread the original question (based on its use of the term "application" when it meant "extension module"). When you're talking about loading incompatible extension modules into Python, the error result should be the same; a 32 bit DLL (extension modules are just a minor special case of DLLs on Windows) is incompatible with a 64 bit Python executable, and a 64 bit DLL is incompatible with a 32 bit Python executable, for the same basic reason, and the error message (derived from the Windows error code returned when trying to dynamically load a DLL with incompatible bit-ness) would be the same.

---

**Original answer about applications vs. modules preserved for posterity, but not relevant to the OP:**

---

It's definitely not the same error; launching a 64 bit program isn't importing a module at all, so it wouldn't raise `ImportError`.

For that matter, as long as the OS is 64 bit and supports running a mix of 32 and 64 bit processes, 32 bit Python shouldn't experience a problem launching a 64 bit program; the problem is mixing and matching 32 and 64 bit code in the same process; two unrelated processes can have whatever bit-ness the OS/hardware support.

Comment: I've just gone to some lengths to check this - the error is actually the same. I think you may have misunderstood what I meant by `loading` I have changed this to `importing` in the question to make it totally clear I'm importing `64bit` code into `32bit` python

Comment: see my post above - I am unsure if this contradicts your first assertion, *"It's definitely not the same error"* or, rather, complements your caveat, *"problem is mixing and matching 32 and 64 bit code in the same process"* - please not that I appreciate your answer and my answer is not meant to contradict your own, rather I am genuinely interested in understanding this properly

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane: Yeah, I misread your question as "Importing a 64 bit module into 32 bit Python gets this error; will launching a 64 bit application from 32 bit Python get the same error?" The problem is that you refer to "applications", when you really mean "extension modules" ("applications" means some top-level executable that can be launched as a completely separate process, e.g. with `subprocess.run(["myapplication"])` which isn't loaded directly into Python at all).

Comment: No worries, it was my fault not being precise on a Friday evening!

Answer (score 0):

In Q&A style ... On a 64bit Windows Machine

- Downloaded [`python`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/) directly from `python.org` in `32bit`
- Downloaded `pyFFTW` dlls for both `32bit` and `64bit` from [`gohlke/pythonlibs/`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and the `.pyd` files

Running both imports...

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyfftw32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import pyfftw64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Thus loading a `64bit` application in a  also gives the same `ImportError`

I also checked this with other 64bit `.pyd` binaries which gave a similar error.

Comment: Ah, I misread your original question. You're not talking about "applications" at all, you're talking about *modules* (extension modules to be precise).